# How do I install npm package into Cypress container?

Tags: docker, npm, cypress

I'm trying to install `randomstring` package into Cypress container because my tests are using it.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM cypress/base:17.8.0

RUN npm install randomstring@1.2.2
RUN npm install cypress@7.0.0
COPY . /e2e
RUN npm cypress run
```

error output I'm getting:

```
1 error occurred:
    * Status: The command '/bin/sh -c npm install randomstring@1.2.2 cypress@7.0.0' returned a non-zero code: 1, Code: 1
```

I'm aware that Cypress/base image comes with operating system and dependencies required in order to run Cypress but I'm not sure if `npm` is included.

What is the right way to install packages into Cypress container ?

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason to use base image?
Have you tried with `cypress/included:7.0.0`, which already has cypress + browsers installed.
Furthermore it's better to keep all your dependencies (`randomstring` included) in `package.json` file where they belong, copy it over and call `npm install` or `npm ci`.